# "People struggle to fit" vs "People struggle fitting"

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to write "struggle fitting"? If so, is there a difference between "struggle fitting" and "struggle to fit"?

> Many people struggle fitting / to fit into the modern academic environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the more correct answer is

> Many people struggle to fit into the modern academic environment

From a more literal meaning.

"Fitting in" is a correct construction. Using it in your sentence as it is would likely be understood by most native speakers. However, it is not quite correct when used like this, perhaps because in+to is not the same as into.
Instead

> Many people in the modern academic environment struggle (fitting in)/(to fit in)

Is a more appropriate, and correct, construction using the phrase "fitting in".